# Import id(Attribute) from other class

Tags: java, class, object

So I have a Class called Major which holds the respective majorId, and I have the class Student which attends a certain Major, and I would like to know if it is possible while declaring the variables for the student to somehow import the majorId, without using Setter or Getter functions, a faster simpler way maybe?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student extends Person {
    private static String cod;
    public String Major.majorId; //?????????? This is what I was trying to do
    private ArrayList<Subject> subjectList;
}

public class Major {
    private String majorId;
    private ArrayList<Student> studentList;
}
```

Comment: Think about it, How would you know which `Major`'s `majorId` to use during declaration?

Answer (score 0):

The way you call `Major.majorId` is in a static context. In order to do it that way, you have to declare the `majorId` variable inside the `Major` class as `static`.

Keep in mind though, a static variable is part of the class, which means that all the instances of the class will share the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't directly possible, however it isn't best pattern either. If your intent is to only allow access to the `majorId` string, you have a couple clean options:

1. Deconstruction in constructor

By passing the Major object in your constructor you can fetch its id for local usage:

```java
public class Student {
  public final String majorId;
  
  public Student(Major m) {
    this.majorId = m.majorId;
  }
}
```

or, pass the id by itself:

```java
  ...
  public Student(String majorId) { 
    this.majorId = majorId 
  }
```

2. Access level definition

In theory there's not much benefit to avoiding keeping the `Major` object reference in the `Student` class. You can make the major private and only allow access to the majorId value. Really, this is a getter, but it's good pattern.

```java
public class Student {
  private final Major major;

  public Student(Major m) {
    this.major = m;
  }

  public String majorId() {
    return major.majorId;
  }
}
```